# If I have a integrated graphic card on my laptop, how do I determine it model number?

Tags: graphics-card

Ok, I'm trying to get a game, but I need to at least meet the minimum graphic card they listed, but when I check my dxdiag it doesn't show the model number meaning that I have an integrated card (or so I think I don't know if this determines if my card is integrated). So is there anyway to check the mode number of this kind of graphic card, or no.

Comment: ask someone on the internet, they'll know, but do'nt tell them the model of your laptop, or what operating system you are using!

Comment: Tell us the processor you've got and the company listed as the manufacturer of your card.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the video card model via command line in Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/723506/get-the-video-card-model-via-command-line-in-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Device manager would show it.

[image]

It should be in control panel or you can search for it to find it.