# ffmpeg windows - how to check if graphics card supports nvenc encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm writing a custom GUI for some ffmpeg tasks, but it will also be used for older computers which don't support GPU encoding. So before I try to encode using a ffmpeg binary compiled with the flag --enable-nvenc, I want to check if the computer system supports it. Otherwise I'd have to change my command-line options.

What is the best way to approach this? Is there a command-line utility that can supply me with the information I need to see if GPU encoding is supported by the graphics card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_NVENC)

> **Nvidia NVENC** is a feature in its graphics cards that performs H.264 video encoding, offloading this compute-intensive task from the CPU. It was **introduced with the Kepler-based GeForce 600 series in March 2012**

So check for a Kepler based Nvidia 6xx or newer card. As some of the lower chips are Fermi based they may not support the core, you need to check for Kepler GKxxx architecture chips and ignore the Fermi GFxxx chips.

[GPU-z](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) supports a `-dump` command which will [apparently export the information to an XML file](https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/gpu-z-command-line-options.120173/) which could then be grepped for a relevant GPU model number.

You'd need to grep for

- [GKxxx](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_700_series) (Kepler, 6xx & 7xx series cards)
- [GMxxx](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_900_series) (Maxwell 9xx series)
- [GPxxx](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_10_series) (Pascal 10xx series)

To stick purely to the command line

```
wmic path win32_VideoController get name
```

Will give you the model name of the graphics card, which you can then work with and potentially infer support from.

The `wmic` command was originally from [Get the video card model via command line in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/723506/get-the-video-card-model-via-command-line-in-windows)

Comment: Nice idea, but unfortunately GPU-Z shows it's start-screen briefly when being called from the command-line. It seems there is no /silent switch for it to really work as a command-line utility. Is there another solution?

Comment: @Taapo  Any of the answers at https://superuser.com/questions/723506/get-the-video-card-model-via-command-line-in-windows help?

Comment: @Mukubai: that's helpful, since it outputs the model of the graphics card. So I would need to grep for the kepler based name again. You might need to update your answer to include "wmic path win32_VideoController get name" - then I can mark it as the valid answer, since it doesn't need any external programs. I'll have to test on a couple of workstations to confirm it is giving the right information in all instances. Thanks for the research!

Comment: @Taapo I've added the command. I don't have an Nvidia card accessible at the moment to see what exactly is output. Take care when using it that you don't assume that *all* 6xx series cards support nvenc, as I mentioned some of that series have older chips that do not support it.