# How to check if my video card run ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.265

How can I discover if my **video card** suports and `ffmpeg` **h265** encode? exist any comand to check it?

Comment: Possible dupe of [ffmpeg windows - how to check if graphics card supports nvenc encoding?](https://superuser.com/q/1221536)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ffmpeg windows - how to check if graphics card supports nvenc encoding?](https://superuser.com/questions/1221536/ffmpeg-windows-how-to-check-if-graphics-card-supports-nvenc-encoding)